# Unable to merge new file from trunk to my branch

Tags: svn, subclipse, conflict

Here are my steps:

1. switch from trunk to my branch
2. perform a merge from a trunks subdirectory to my branch subdirectory, i.e.
   svn merge https:.../trunk/Class@2209 https:...branches/mybranch/Class@HEAD /Users/me/.../Class

The response I get:
--- Merging differences between repository URLs into '/Users/me/.../Class':
   C /Users/me/.../Class/NewFileYouDoNotHave.php
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1

Revision 2209 is the same revision that NewFileYouDoNotHave.php was added to the trunk. I understand that I want the previous version.  However, the previous trunk revision is older than the branches latest revision.  (so i guess someone updated the branch and didn't include my file).

To correct this I read that the conflict probably originates from svn's confusion on which files are in which revision. So I deleted NewFileYouDoNotHave.php and committed it to trunk.  Then added it and committed it back into trunk.  I switched to my branch and performed the merge again, but I'm still getting the same results.

From my experience this previous week, I know that if I switch back to trunk (right now i'm in the branch) that Subclipse will drop the connection to svn.  I will no longer be able to access the Team menu item and perform svn commands through the Subclipse GUI but I will still be able to run svn commands in terminal.

Skill:noob
SVN: svn, version 1.6.5 (r38866)
Subclipse: 1.0.6

I would really appreciate any advice, insights, etc. !!!

Comment: In my experience with Eclipse & svn and non-trivial operations, I've always found that I need to shutdown Eclipse, do what I need to do via Tortoise (assuming Windows due to your URLs) and then re-start Eclipse & refresh. Not that that helps with your particular problem, but it is good to remember.

Comment: ah that might help Subclipse not drop svn when I switch back to trunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When merging you need to be in the working copy of the code base you want to merge to (Branch) Then merge from the Trunk version 2209 to Trunk Head to your working copy.

in other word you are merging in changes from v:2209 to the head of the trunk code to your branch.

**[EDIT]**
When merging you should remember the code you merge is a range of changes from one branch. so from the Branch you want changes from 2209 to 2221 in the trunk. Select the branch as the working copy, merge from Trunk @ 2209 and merge to Trunk 2221. This will grab changes 2209 to 2221 in the trunk and merge them into the Branch that is your working copy.

Comment: Yep, I'm in branch when all of these commands are performed.  Anything particular that showed I wasn't?

Comment: Right I see that.
try this- 
svn merge [trunk][from version] [trunk][to version] [branch working 
copy dir]

Comment: Thank you corn3lius! You were right, I misunderstood the SVN syntax. Now I can get on with my life!